# Merging 2 json files into new json with no duplicates

Tags: arrays, json, merge, jq

My dedicated servers are generating 2 laptime arrays and I would like to use a script to merge them into a single, new json file, with duplicate "steamids" removed (and kept grouped together as they still are) and both arrays under a single loggedTimes {} (so I can feed it to a html script that produces laptimes and a leaderboard). In other words, I want the structure to remain.
The [first laptime file](https://touristenfahrten.duckdns.org/laptimes_data_ams.json) and the [second laptime file](https://touristenfahrten.duckdns.org/laptimes_data_kow.json) go through the following command

```
jq 'reduce . as $item ({}; . * $item)' laptimes_data_ams.json laptimes_data_kow.json > laptimes.json
```

to then generate the (badly) [merged laptime file](https://touristenfahrten.duckdns.org/laptimes.json).
I can get a file reduced but can't get any further than that. I checked threads by other around here and whenever I try their suggestions the script just refuses to work. Anybody available to lend me a hand in generating a working script to keep this final structure post-merge?

```
{
"loggedTimes" : {
    steamids" : {
        "idnumber1" : "name1",
        "idnumber2" : "name2"
    },
    "vehicles" : {
        "vehiclenumber1" : {
            "laptimes" : {
                "idnumber1" : {
                    "lapTime" : time1,
                    "logtime" : log1,
                    "name" : "name 1",
                    "rank" : rank1,
                    "refId" : id1,
                    "vehicleid" : vehiclenumber1,
                    "wet" : 0
                },
                "idnumber2" : {
                    "lapTime" : time2,
                    "logtime" : log2,
                    "name" : "name 2",
                    "rank" : rank2,
                    "refId" : id2,
                    "vehicleid" : vehiclenumber1,
                    "wet" : 0                
                }
            }
        }
        "vehiclesnumber2" : {
        //you get the idea by now
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For future reference, please follow the [mcve] guidelines -- with an emphasis on *minimal*. That way, you can also show the expected result more easily.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified how the merge is to be performed, but one option would be to let the key-value pairs in the second file dominate.  In that case, you could write:

```
jq -n '
  input as $one
  | input as $two
  | ($one + $two)
  | .loggedTimes.steamids = ($one.loggedTimes.steamids + $two.loggedTimes.steamids)
'  1.json 2.json
```

With your input, this produces output from which the following is an extract:

```
{
  "loggedTimes": {
    "steamids": {
      "76561197960277005": "[DECOCO]koker_SZ",
      "76561197960436395": "JOJO",
      ...
    },
    "vehicles": {
      "-1142039519": {
        "lapTimes": {}
      },
      "-1201605905": {
        "lapTimes": {
          "76561197984026143": {
            "lapTime": 609101,
            "logtime": 1606516985,
            "name": "Night Dick",
            "rank": 1,
            "refId": 36032,
            "vehicleId": -1201605905,
            "wet": 0
          }
        }
      }
     ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah my bad. Yes I wanted to preserve the steamids key. Basically I want the current structure to remain, so steamids stays in its own group but gets a duplicate check and the vehicles get grouped (there won't be duplicates there).
I managed to get the steamids regrouped and duplicates removed but I am still struggling to add the vehicles {} after the steamids{}. Any tip as to how to proceed?

Comment: You absolute legend! I just had to add   | .loggedTimes.vehicles = ($one.loggedTimes.vehicles + $two.loggedTimes.vehicles) behind to regroup the lap times and bam. It works. Thank you very very much peak. You can take a look at what you helped create [over here](https://touristenfahrten.duckdns.org) .